# On Caloric Surplus

Tags: diet

I am a 6’1” 19 year old male weighing about 81kg on average, I regularly exercise (4-5 days a week weightlifting) and have a fairly physical job. I am on my feet lifting things around nearly every day.

My question is what calories do I need to eat to gain muscle slowly, I want to be about 87-90kg of lean muscle in the next two years or so.

According to most calorie calculators it’s about 3,000kcal with 270+ grams of protein. This seems completely unreasonable to me as I understand 1g protein per pound of body weight is a good measure. I would appreciate advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gram of protein is 4 calories.. so you can take your weight

176lbish

270-176=94

94*4=376 calories

So replace 94 g of protein with 94g carbs or  40g healthy fat or a mixture depending on your goals(in this case since you're adding weight I'd do carbs)

Carbs =4 calories
Fat=9 calories

With both exercise and physical job, it's considered very intense on the BMR calculator.. and a rough estimate gave me 3400 calories. I'd do 3000 and if you aren't gaining weight try adding an extra 400-500 a day. I also agree that more than 1g per lb isn't worth it and I don't like to eat 5-6 times the daily recommended amount, I just feel like it's probably not best for a healthy body based on some studies on kidneys.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it is very helpful. With regards to 270g of protein I had been doing it for a few days and I haven’t felt good because of it. Very sluggish and stomach aches frequently.

Comment: Sure no problem. Yeah I've been seeing a GI doctor, and he also told me to stick to whey isolate instead of whey concentrate as well. So try to stick to that protein for workouts, and use meals to get protein at other times, otherwise you'll have bad GI issues like the stomach aches.

Comment: Like @AceCabbie says, definitely watch your protein sources. Vegetarian options for example can ok, but can also give you GI issues because of fiber and just general volume.